# Как отобразить заголовок HTTP запроса используя HttpURLConnection(Java)

Tags: java, веб-программирование, сервер, http, httpurlconnection

Имеется небольшой код(нашел в интернете), для отправки запроса на сервер и получения ответа от него. Но я хотел бы вывести на экран сам заголовок запроса с помощью метода `getRequestProperties()`, но у меня не получается. `Map` не заполняется.

```
package Lab2;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Requests2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL myUrl = new URL("http://pro-java.ru");

        HttpURLConnection myUrlCon =
                (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();


        Map<String, List<String>> Map = myUrlCon.getRequestProperties();
        Set<String> Field = Map.keySet();
        for(String k : Field) {
            System.out.println("Ключ: " + k + " Значение: "
                    + Map.get(k).toString());
        }


        System.out.println("Метод запроса: " +
                myUrlCon.getRequestMethod());


        // Вывести код ответа

        System.out.println("Ответное сообщение: " +
                myUrlCon.getResponseMessage());

        // Получить список полей и множество ключей из заголовка

        Map<String, List<String>> myMap = myUrlCon.getHeaderFields();
        Set<String> myField = myMap.keySet();

        // Вывести все ключи и значения из заголовка
        for(String k : myField) {
            System.out.println("Ключ: " + k + " Значение: "
                    + myMap.get(k).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы отправляете запрос без заголовков. Для того, чтобы отправить запрос с заголовком, его нужно установить с помощью

[setRequestProperty(String key, String value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Вот что написано в документации по этому методу:

> Устанавливает общее свойство запроса.  Если свойство с ключом уже существует, замените его значение новым значением.
>
> ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. HTTP требует, чтобы все свойства запроса, которые могут иметь несколько экземпляров с одним и тем же ключом, использовали синтаксис списка, разделенного запятыми, который позволяет добавлять несколько свойств в одно свойство.
>
> Параметры:
>
> key - ключевое слово, по которому запрос известен (например, "Accept").
>
> value - значение, связанное с ним.
>
> Выдает:
>
> IllegalStateException - если уже подключен;
> NullPointerException - если ключ равен нулю.